# How to read from std::cin to istringstream

Tags: c++, stream, std, istringstream

I would like to parse date in format [mm/dd/yy]:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    struct tm time;
    std::istringstream ss;
    std::cout << "enter string [mm/dd/yy/]: ";
    std::cin >> ss;
    ss >> std::get_time(&time, "%D");
    std::cout << time.tm_wday << std::endl;
}
```

But I cannot read from `std::cin` to `std::istringstream`, but why?

2. I am also seeking for explanation about the buffers. There I have 2 buffers (cin -> istream, and istringstream), which provide different buffer (one for "string", the other for "screen - stdout"), but why the two cannot interact one another, when they are still just a `streambuf`. How is even the `streambuf` implemented in C++? Is it an array? a struct?, Could I find the source implementation of it somewhere?

Comment: Why not directly `std::cin >> std::get_time(&time, "%D");`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `std::string` and `std::getline`:

```
std::string input_text;
std::getline(std::cin, input_text);
std::istringstream input_text_stream(input_text);
```

Answer (score 0):

No need of intermediate `std::istringstream`, you might do directly:

```
std::cin >> std::get_time(&time, "%D");
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/cxTOI6)

To substitute underlying buffer, you have to call `rdbuf`:

```
std::istringstream ss;
std::cout << "enter string [mm/dd/yy/]: ";
ss.basic_ios::rdbuf(std::cin.rdbuf()); // substitute internal ss buffer with std::cin one
ss >> std::get_time(&time, "%D");
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/RWsWKG)

Comment: But could you also provide an explanation, why 2 buffers (istream - cin, istringstream) cannot interact with one another? Is there a way I could see the implementation of `streambuf`?

Comment: Added more complicated version to substitute internal buffer.

Comment: You might find implementation from open source compilers.